# Android saving state of checkbox if exit app

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have 5 checkboxs and when they are clicked they set a boolean in an abstract class to true or false using a onCheckedChangeListener. Example:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) 
            {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    CheckboxData.checked = true;
                }
                else if(!isChecked)
                {
                    CheckboxData.checked = false;
                }

            }

        });
```

However when I leave the app and return the checkboxes are not clicked anymore, yet the boolean values are still true. How can I make the app remember that the check boxes are clicked.? Should I just check the boolean values in the main activity onCreate and set the checkboxs to checked or not then or is there a better/faster way to make the app remember the checkboxs states?

Just added this in the main activities onCreate method:

```
      if(CheckboxData.checked)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkbox.setChecked(true);
    }
```

But it does nothing

Comment: You need to call setChecked(your_boolean) in onCreate()

Comment: is Oncreate of the main activity called each time you open the app?

Comment: Yes.. Refer the following link for more about android lifecycle
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html

Comment: Its better you use sharedpref for saving the checkbox state instead of  using abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `Activity` get `destroyed`  check the checkbox state if true , and add the checkbox state in `shared Preference`

```
     @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    if(CheckboxData.checked){
     SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("private preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            prefs.edit()
                .putBoolean("CheckboxData",true)
                .commit();
   }
    super. onDestroy();

   }
```

And when `Activity` is launched back, In `onCreate`  check for the checkbox state in preference and if true enable the checkbox

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("private preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  boolean isChecked = prefs.getBoolean("CheckboxData",false);
  if(isChecked)
  checkBoxView.setChecked(true)
```

Comment: Thank you, but how will I ensure the onCheckedChangeListener is only added once, I assume when I open the activity again it adds another listener making two?

Comment: Listeners are canceled when Activity destroyed. So don't worry. It will have only one instance

Comment: @Libin - According to Activity lifecycle notes, onDestroy might not be called; pre-Honeycomb only `onPause` was guaranteed; more recently `onStop` is guaranteed. See which methods are marked `killable` in table after http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle. The system is permitted to kill app after a killable method, without calling the remaining methods in the lifecycle. Most notably, may not reach onDestroy.