# got setSilent error when trying to implement SharedPreferences to save state of a checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save the state of a checkbox while using SharedPreferences. I have spend hours on this problem...which I sure is easy to solve. I have been following the tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

However, I do not understand what setSilent is and what I have to change it to within my own code. setSilent has been changed to checked in the below code based on one of the answers. I have searched through stackoverflow a lot and found loads of related answers but nothing has worked and the setSilent (sometimes a different name) error is always persistent. I have posted my code below.

**SuikodenFragment.java** -- The error is here.

```
Boolean checked;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public  View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.suikoden_main_activity1, container, false);
    // you can use findViewById() using the above 'view'
    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.suikodenList1);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    checked = true;

    return view;
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();  // Always call the superclass method first
    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(suikodenprefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("Tick the Box", checked);
    checked(isChecked); 
    //if(isChecked)
    //checkBox.setChecked(true); 
}
```

The code below is placing the checkbox state which might help understand my problem.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) expListView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxTick);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    if (isChecked)
        // Add the tick to the box
        //Log.d(TAG, "Tick the box");
        checked = true;
     else
        // Remove the tick in the box
        //Log.d(TAG, "Untick the box");
         checked = false;
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
   super.onStop();
   SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(suikodenprefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("Tick the Box",checked).commit();
}
```

I really hope someone can help with this. It may seem like a stupid problem but if it can be solved then I can complete a huge section of my app. The following link is the closest to my own code...but when i implement their solution, checkBoxView flags up as an error [Android saving state of checkbox if exit app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704505/android-saving-state-of-checkbox-if-exit-app). I am a beginner so I apologise...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class variable which gets changed in your onCheckedChangedListener and then save it in shared preferences in your onStop() method.

Comment: its gunna sound stupid but i dont quite understand, have you got an example or a link to a basic example?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your activity declare a Boolean variable, lets call it checked.

```
Boolean checked;
```

It's good practice to initialize a variable so do that in you onCreate method.

```
checked = true;
```

In your onCheckedChanged method set the value of 'checked' to true or false depending on the state.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) expListView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_tick);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
if (isChecked)
   checked = true;
 else
 checked = false;
}
```

In your onStop method save the value of your checked variable.

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
super.onStop();
SharedPreferences      settings=getActivity().getSharedPreferences(suikodenprefs,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("Tick the box",checked).commit();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, I had no idea how to do this. I think I must be missing something though. Because i done all you have asked but...I changed the setSilent(isChecked); to checked(isChecked); (which I think is what i had to do) and checked(isChecked); is still showing error. I have updated the code. Thank you so much for helping me with this